# Firebase Function Deployment Possible EventEmitter memory leak

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Every time I deploy my firebase functions I get this in the log for each function:

> (node:2) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

my node version is `v8.1.3`

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.6.0",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^0.15.2",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.2.1",
    "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.24.9",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.24.9",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "piexifjs": "^1.0.3",
    "rand-token": "^0.4.0",
    "raven": "^2.4.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.22.1",
    "request": "^2.83.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

All of my functions work perfectly fine, but its getting close to production time and I don't like the look of this, does anyone know what it's about?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I've tried that but the errors wont go away

Comment: @DevShadow I just started getting this error. After deploying all my functions, all of them start throwing the error. Did you figure out what was going on?

Comment: @DevShadow Did you get an answer for this?